# Debug mode throwing NullPointer Exception in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

so I have a class using graphics in java 1.8 and I am using Eclipse. The thing is when I run the program normally it works, but when I want to use debug mode it just falls because of NullPointer Exception. The terminal writes this:

```
main.Game at localhost:54045    
    Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Running) 
    Thread [Thread-2] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
        owns: TrueTypeFont  (id=40) 
        owns: Win32FontManager  (id=41) 
        TrueTypeFont.open(boolean) line: not available  
        TrueTypeFont.verify(boolean) line: not available    
        TrueTypeFont.<init>(String, Object, int, boolean, boolean) line: not available  
        TrueTypeFont.<init>(String, Object, int, boolean) line: not available   
        Win32FontManager(SunFontManager).resolveFontFiles(HashSet<String>, ArrayList<String>) line: not available   
        Win32FontManager(SunFontManager).resolveWindowsFonts() line: not available  
        Win32FontManager(SunFontManager).getFullNameToFileMap() line: not available 
        Win32FontManager(SunFontManager).findFontFromPlatform(String, int) line: not available  
        Win32FontManager(SunFontManager).findFont2D(String, int, int) line: not available   
        Font.getFont2D() line: not available    
        Font.access$000(Font) line: not available   
        Font$FontAccessImpl.getFont2D(Font) line: not available 
        FontUtilities.getFont2D(Font) line: not available   
        SunGraphics2D.checkFontInfo(FontInfo, Font, FontRenderContext) line: not available  
        SunGraphics2D.getFontInfo() line: not available 
        SolidTextRenderer(GlyphListPipe).drawString(SunGraphics2D, String, double, double) line: not available  
        SunGraphics2D.drawString(String, int, int) line: not available  
        Menu.render(Graphics) line: 35  
        Game.render() line: 115 
        Game.run() line: 58 
        Thread.run() line: not available    
    Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)
```

The code on Menu.render(Graphics) line 35 is g.drawString() and when I comment lines where I am setting the font with g.setFont(font) the NullPointer is not thrown. I can work without debug mode but I want to fix this... Don't you know what can it be? Thanks.

Comment: Still add a [mcve]

Comment: I think people are being a little too much trigger-happy with the close-votes. OP wants his app to work the same way in debug mode as it works in standard execution mode, that is avoid having an NPE thrown by `TrueTypeFont`, a class of the JRE. The code of `Menu` should be posted (at least the line invoking `SunGraphics2D.drawString`), but I doubt it will be really useful.

Comment: I have the same pb while invoking the getAllFonts method, with the same stack trace at the end... Did you finally find a way to fix this ?